# Having trouble to use justify-content: space-between; in react-bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

My problem is that justify-content: space-between seems doesnt work in my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../styles/headerStyle.scss';
const Header = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand='lg' bg='dark' variant='dark'>
      <Navbar.Brand href='#home'>React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav' />
      <Navbar.Collapse id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
        <Nav>
          <div className='container'>
            <Nav.Link>Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link>Pricing</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title='Dropdown' id='collasible-nav-dropdown'>
              <NavDropdown.Item href='#action/3.1'>Action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href='#action/3.2'>
                Another action
              </NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href='#action/3.3'>Something</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <NavDropdown.Item href='#action/3.4'>
                Separated link
              </NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
            <Nav.Link>More deets</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href='#memes'>
              Dank memes
            </Nav.Link>
          </div>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  </React.Fragment>
);
export default Header;
```

Here is stylesheet:

```
.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Here is my current result:
[current header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCW8C.png)

Here is the tutorial I follow,  I am not sure where do I make mistakes in my code. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are  you sure that your `nav` items are `flex` elements?

Comment: It's possible that your container doesn't have set width so it extends the full width. If I'm right, the `justify-content` is working fine, but, without the container being larger than its contents, there's no space to apply between the contents.

Comment: From the react-bootstrap document: The base Nav component is built with flexbox and provide a strong foundation for building all types of navigation components, So I think they are flex elements.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, you are correct, after I add a 100% width in the  Nav component. It works!